# Questions relating commutator subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Given $ G'' $ is a cyclic group, how to show that $ G'' \subseteq Z(G') $ ?
I can prove the result that $ G'\subseteq C_G(N) $ for a normal, cyclic subgroup $N$ using $N/C$ theorem but can't relate with this problem.

Comment: What is $G''$? $[G',G]$ or $[G',G']$?

Comment: It usually denotes the second derived group, which is the second option you list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $G^{"} \lhd G.$ Therefore the conjugation action of $G$ induces automorphisms of $G^{"}.$ Therefore, $G^{"}$ can play the role of the cyclic normal subgroup $N$
in the situation which you seem to understand,

Comment: But how to relate $ C_{G'}(G'') $ with $ Z(G') $ ?

Comment: It is certainly the case that $G^{"} \subseteq G^{'},$ and you have proved that $G^{'} \subseteq C_{G}(G^{"}),$ so you have all the information you need.

Comment: It maybe very simple but still I am not getting it, how do you show that $ G'' $ is normal in $G$ ?

Comment: If you know about characteristic subgroups, notice that you have $G^{"} {\rm char} G^{'} \lhd G.$